# Changing SVG color via CSS, SVG color wont change

Tags: css, svg

Heres my code:

HTML:

```
<img src="../img/icon-play.svg" class="play-button-svg">
```

SASS:

```
.play-button-svg
padding-left: 10px
fill: $white
```

The icon keep its original color and does not change to white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using SVG as image or background image you cant control with CSS. If you want '.play-button-svg' to work, you  should place SVG code which will look like-

```
<svg ...>
  <path .../>
</svg>
```

Then apply class-

```
   <svg ...>
      <path class="play-button-svg" .../>
    </svg>
```

and now your CSS will work :)

Comment: Interesting. So I can just put the svg code in between <svg> tags? 

Would this work?
HTML:
<svg class="play-button-svg"> (code from svg) </svg> 

SASS:
.play-button-svg
padding-left: 10px
fill: $white

Comment: @klmitchell2 SVG code is itself enclosed in <svg> tag , just copy paste text and apply class to element like you do in html that's it  :)